# What is the most elegant way to get the value in an array, minimizing a certain class attribute?

Tags: ruby, sorting

Say I have the following class:

```
class Person
    def initialize(name, age)
        @name = name
        @age = age
    end

    def get_age
        return @age
    end
end
```

And I have an array of `Person` objects.  Is there a concise, Ruby-like way to get the person with the minimum (or maximum) age?  What about sorting them by it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do:

```
people_array.min_by(&:get_age)
people_array.max_by(&:get_age)
people_array.sort_by(&:get_age)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been answered properly but, since you are interested in doing things in a **Ruby-like way**,
I am going to show you a better Ruby-like way to define your `Person` class.

If do you do not have behaviour (methods, etc.) in your class, the simplest way is using a Struct:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :age)

# example of use
person = Person.new("My name", 21)
```

Otherwise create a custom class like this, using attr_reader and a hash of arguments:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :age

  def initialize(args = {})
    @name = args[:name]
    @age = args[:age]
  end
end

# example of use
person = Person.new(:name => "My name", :age => 21)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got an array named `array` having 5 different instances of Person.

To get the older person

```
for person in array
  olderperson = person if maxperson.get_age < person.get_age
end
```

And for sorting them

```
array.sort! { |a,b| a.get_age <=> b.get_age }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
youngest_person = people.select { |p| p.get_age == people.map(&:get_age).min }
```